# HTML Page selection

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am coding a contact page in bootstrap 3.0 and the problem is that when i enter some values in the contact form , and try selecting the entered values , either with my mouse or by pressing 
CTRL + SHIFT + Left arrow key , nothing selects . i don't know why . can somebody help me out with this ?

thank you .

below is the code for my contact form.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8 things">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                    <form action="send.php" method="POST" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">
                                    Name</label>
                                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">
                                    Email Address</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" /></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Phone">
                                    Phone Number</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <input name="phone" type="Phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Contact number" required="required" /></div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">
                                    Message</label>
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required="required"
                                    placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                                Send Message</button>

                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-success pull-right" id="btnReset">
                                Reset</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: It´s not HTML/CSS problem, you propably you there a JavaScript which cause that.

Comment: @panther Like what kind of javascript can 'cause that problem , and yes i have used alot of Js and Jquery .

Comment: I don´t want what you used. Don´t you codes you don´t understand them. It´s my advice.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem with a fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @HenriHietala , I will try . Give me some time

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your code here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EypHn

It seems to work Ok.

Make sure your  tags are correct.

eg:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">         </script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
     <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope that helps.